# PHPのデフォルトのロケールを設定する方法

Tags: php

お世話になります。

PHPでsetlocaleを使わずに、ロケールの指定をしたいのですが、php.ini等でできるのでしょうか。
　ちなみに、.htaccessに

```
SetEnv LANG "ja_JP.UTF-8"
```

と記載してみましたが、反映されていないようです。
　何か良い方法があれば、教えていただけると幸いです。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

出来るようです。

[PHP7.2をインストール後のphp.iniの設定](https://qiita.com/nao_tuboyaki/items/9615166e2374a565af80)

> PHPをインストール後に最低限デフォルト値から変更する項目を書いておく
>   ※書いてある項目以外にもあるとは思います。
>   対象バージョン
>   PHP 7.2
>   php.ini設定
>
> ```
> ; デフォルト文字コード
> default_charset = UTF-8
> ;　mbstringのデフォルトの言語
> mbstring.language = Japanese
> ;　HTTP入力文字のエンコーディングを内部文字のエンコーディングに自動変換なし
> mbstring.encoding_translation = Off
> ;　文字コードを自動検出する際の優先順位
> mbstring.detect_order = UTF-8,SJIS,EUC-JP,JIS,ASCII
> ; タイムゾーンを日本標準時間
> date.timezone = Asia/Tokyo
> ; HTTPのレスポンスによりPHPのバージョン情報を非表示
> expose_php = Off
>
> ; 以下はPHP5.6以降で非推奨になっているのでコメントアウトしておく
> ;mbstring.internal_encoding = 
> ;mbstring.http_input = 
> ;mbstring.http_output =
> ```

ちなみに、Apacheによる設定は、.htaccess ではなく、以下でやるようです。
[CentOSでApacheを日本語ロケール(ja_JP.utf8)で起動する](http://maeda.farend.ne.jp/blog/2010/01/05/apache-httpd-lang/)

> ApacheをRHEL/CentOSのパッケージで導入した場合(デフォルト)
>   ja_JP.utf8に設定するには、 /etc/sysconfig/httpd に以下の行を追加します。

```
HTTPD_LANG=ja_JP.utf8
```

> Apacheをソースコードからビルドしてインストールした場合
>   /usr/local/apache2/bin/envvars に以下の行を追加します。このファイルは apachectl 実行時に読み込まれます。

```
LANG=ja_JP.utf8
export LANG
```

類似の注意
[PHP動作環境で先頭の漢字のみ文字化けするケースがある](http://www.cross-ring.net/web/DPOW/linux_server_setting/apache/616)

> ちなみに、httpd.confに「SetEnv LANG ～」と書くことによる変更はできないようです。

Comment: お世話になります。やはり.htaccessではできないのですね。Apacheの設定を変更しないといけないようなので、今回は諦めます。ありがとうございました。